# Instrumented tests not found with custom instrumentation - conditional instrumentation?

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I have a working Android app with a manifest containing this `<instrumentation>` node

```
<instrumentation
    android:name=".MyInstrumentation"
    android:targetPackage="my.package"/>
```

I have instrumented tests also, but when I run those I get this

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r-e debug false my.package.test/my.package.MyInstrumentation
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{my.package.test/my.package.MyInstrumentation}android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: my.package.test/my.package.MyInstrumentation
. onError: commandError=true message=INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: my.package.test/my.package.Instrumentation
```

and tests are not run.

If I remove the instrumentation declaration from the manifest it works fine, when I run the tests like this I get this

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false my.package.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Tests ran to completion.
```

`androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` is the instrumentation that gets executed.

This happens when I run the tests from Android Studio and also when I execute `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`.

How can I tell `gradle` or Android Studio that I want to run the tests with the `AndroidJUnitRunner` instrumentation? With still allowing my own.

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your build.gradle file, and try

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```